# Probability Question on Dice with condition

Tags: conditional-probability

[self-study]
Imagine you have 24 boxes. Upon opening any box there is probability of 4.73% that you will find pearls of some value. The value of any pearl can be {4,5,6,7,8}. What is the probability that value of total pearls after opening all boxes is atleast 19?

I tried using simulation on 'R' and was able to get answer. But I want analytical solution. Can somebody please help.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is at most one pearl per box? The values are uniformly distributed between {4,5,6,7,8}?

Comment: Yes, that's correct only Pearl can be found and value are unifromly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is at most one pearl per box and the values are uniformly distributed between {4,5,6,7,8}.

A general R function to calculate the probability:

```
library(data.table)

ppearlval <- function(thresh, nbox, ppearl, vals) {
  k <- length(vals)
  nmin <- ceiling(thresh/max(vals))
  nmax <- ceiling(thresh/min(vals)) - 1
  pOut <- pbinom(nmin - 1, nbox, ppearl, FALSE)
  
  addpearl <- function(dt) {
    dt[,.(v = c(outer(v, vals, "+")), p = rep(p/k, k))][,.(p = sum(p)), v]
  }
  
  if (nmin <= nmax) {
    dt <- data.table(v = vals, p = 1/k)
    if (nmin > 1) for (i in 2:nmin) dt <- addpearl(dt)
    pOut <- pOut - dt[v < thresh, sum(p)]*dbinom(nmin, nbox, ppearl)
    
    if (nmax > nmin) {
      for (i in (nmin + 1):nmax) {
        dt <- addpearl(dt)
        pOut <- pOut - dt[v < thresh, sum(p)]*dbinom(i, nbox, ppearl)
      }
    }
  }
  
  pOut
}
```

For a sanity check, a function to simulate the values:

```
rpearlval <- function(n, nbox, ppearl, vals) {
  cspearl <- cumsum(c(1L, rbinom(n, nbox, ppearl)))
  diff(cumsum(c(0, sample(vals, cspearl[length(cspearl)], 1)))[cspearl])
}
```

Get the probability for the question asked.

```
ppearlval(19, 24, 0.0473, 4:8)
#> [1] 0.05725165
mean(rpearlval(1e6, 24, 0.0473, 4:8) >= 19)
#> [1] 0.057714
```

Check the performance of `ppearlval` with 1,000 boxes:

```
system.time(p1 <- ppearlval(300, 1e3, 0.0473, 4:8))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.16    0.14    0.14
system.time(p2 <- mean(rpearlval(1e6, 1e3, 0.0473, 4:8) >= 300))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    2.80    0.23    3.03
c(exact = p1, simulation = p2)
#>      exact simulation 
#>  0.3448196  0.3444780
```

Comment: Your soltuion is correct. I got the same answer as yours but I want actually more mathematical approach as I'm unable to comprehend it analytically to be honest

Answer (score 0):

The analytical solution is a bit messy, so I would still use R to do the calculations.

The key is to condition on the number of pearls found; call this $X$.

There are only two values of $X$ where you need to do a bit of work. Can you see what they are?

Comment: To be clear - only pear can be found in the box and value of the pearl is unformly distributed. My initial approach is to take complement probability. Let $X$ be the value of pearl given that pearl has been found in the box. Then, I can do $ 1 - ( P(X = 0) + P(X = 4) + P(X = 5)...+ P(X = 18)$. But I'm, not sure whether this is correct approach or how to take it further form here.